# How to send user back to checkout after NAK response?

Tags: commerce

In [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), I need a way to send a user back to their checkout page if the payment gateway responds back with an error.

Right now it kind of bombs out and just tosses a nasty error message to the user and the cart and its contents are "gone", since Drupal marks the Commerce order as complete.

I've tried adding in my custom error handler function something like:
commerce_order_status_update($order, 'checkout_review');
or
commerce_order_status_update($order, 'cart');

But in both cases, the order does remain however some weird things happen, such as if you try to go to /cart you get a cart empty message as well as the shipping information gets dropped.

I'm beginning to think I'm not following the best practice for returning a user properly to their cart following an error in the checkout process.

Comment: What's a _NAK_? The best Google can give me is a `sodium-potassium alloy`, which I suspect isn't what you're going for...

Comment: Sorry, a negative-acknowledge character.  Basically if the payment gateway comes back with an error of any kind.  The error is not important per se.  Rather, I'm more interested in having Drupal see the error and then send the user either back to the cart or checkout page.

Comment: It depends - what's your method for retrieving the response from the payment processor, and at what point in the process do you do that? Or is the response instigated by the processor at the other end (IPN style)?

Comment: Right now I am using hook_commerce_checkout_complete to detect when the order is complete on the Drupal side and interpret the payment gateway's response.

http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_complete/DC

Comment: But how does the NAK get to your server, and what format does it take? What's listening for it, and when do you expect it? Who sends it and how? (is it an IPN post in the background? something in the URL params that gets passed through on return from an off-site page? a response you receive when you contact the processor directly from the server side? etc)

Comment: We have some custom PHP code that sends our order data in XML to the payment gateway and then listens for its response.

Comment: Ah ok, that's an easy one then: when you receive the negative response, use `drupal_goto('cart');`.

Comment: Tried that but I think the problem is Drupal thinks the order is complete and so the order is "gone" and /cart returns an empty cart.

Comment: How can it think the order is complete before your payment processing module has told it the order is complete?? :) Sounds like you have a dodgy bit of code, or maybe a misfiring rule

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the issue is Drupal Commerce does not have a mechanism for knowing if the order is succesful or not.  hook_commerce_checkout_complete runs when the user submits the order and then it's out of Drupal's hands.  

If this is not the best way to proceed, that's okay too.  Just looking for a means of having Drupal send the user back when the order fails.

Comment: It's based on the status of the order - you set the workflow up for that using rules. Your custom code for contacting the payment processor is in a custom Commerce payment processor module, right? Like commerce_paypal etc? You're not just trying to run some arbitrary PHP code at _some_ point in the process? Payment processor modules are a fully-fledged thing with rules and constraints that integrate with the rest of the Commerce workflow - if you haven't written that type of module, that's why you're having problems. If you have, just update the question with the code from the relevant hooks